# Does anyone know how to use the Doxygen Tool in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, doxygen

Specifically I need the yaml for the build definition. I already have Doxygen and Latex installed on the agent machine. Also, I can create Doxygen documentation for the C# Restful API manually using the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to use the Doxygen Tool in Azure DevOps?

To use the Doxygen Tool in Azure DevOps, we need to install required softwares on agent machine:

- Doxygen tool should be installed on the Build agent machine
  (download)
- PdfLatex tool should be installed on the Build agent machine.

Then add the task  Documentation (Doxygen) in the build pipeline to generate the documentation from source code in your repository. On successful generation, the task uploads the file as Build artifact so that it can be downloaded at later time:

[image]

Note: This extension doesn't works with Hosted build agent as of now. So, please use a locally configured build agent.

Besides, if you want to generate YAML documentation, you could try to use the extension [YAML Documentation Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-YAMLGenerator&ssr=false#overview).

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do we look at the generated docs? I see that Azure DevOps has a Documentation section under Repos but that page just tells me that my build doesn't have docs. That page also only links to some old builds for other projects.